# Python socket error 10054, connection was interrupted by remote host

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp, ethernet

i am trying to set up communication with an ethernet device connected to my computer. Connection seems to work ok, when i connect the socket to the device's IP address and port, but when I try to send a command to the device, it returns the [error 10054 - connection was forcibly interrupted by the remote host]. The code I have so far is like this:

```
import socket
import time
import logging



logging.basicConfig(filename='conn.txt', filemode='w')


logging.warning('Starting...')
address = ('192.168.1.23', 23)
soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)


ok = soc.connect_ex(address)


if ok == 0:
    logging.warning('Connected to device ' + str(ok))
else:
    logging.warning('Connection failed ' + str(ok))



### send at command
command = 'AT+SENSOR_IDS'
cmd_to_send = command + '\r\n'
cmd_to_send = cmd_to_send.encode('ascii')
logging.warning('Sending at command')

soc.sendall(cmd_to_send)
logging.warning('at command sent, waiting for echo')


# read echo
echo = soc.recv()
logging.warning('received echo: ' + echo)

print('finished')
```

When i try to "reconnect" with another soc.connect_ex(address), it tells me that the socket is in use.

Thank you for all your help.

---

### EDIT:

So because I don't know much about the device thanks to the lack of documentation, I decided on simulating the problem just using an Echo server and a client example on a localhost. I have this code:

Server side:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ('localhost', 1001)
s.bind(server_address)

s.listen(1)

# looking for clients
while True:
    print('waiting for connection')
    connection, client_address = s.accept()
    # when client connects
    try:
        print('Connection from %s port %s' % client_address )

        # get all the data and echo it back
        while True:
            data = connection.recv(15)
            print('Received:   ' + str(data))

            if not data:
                try:
                    s.sendall(data)
                except:
                    print('echoing data failed')
                break

    finally:
        connection.close()
```

Client side:

```
import socket

address = ('127.0.0.1', 1001)
soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

ok = soc.connect_ex(address)

try:
    if ok == 0:
        print('Connected to device ' + str(ok))
    else:
        print('Connection failed ' + str(ok))
except Exception as e:
    soc.close()
    print("connection not succesful, error returned :", e)

try:
    cmd_to_send = 'AT+SENSOR_IDS\r\n'.encode('ascii')
    bytes_sent = soc.sendall(cmd_to_send)
    if bytes_sent == None:
        print('Command sent succesfully')
    else:
        print('AT command failed to be sent')

    # read echo
    echo = soc.recv()
    print('received echo: ' + echo)
    soc.close()
except:
    try:
        soc.close()
        print('at command or echo reading failed')
    except:
        print('Process finished socket exception occured')
```

After the command is received by the server, it can't be echoed back to the client as the socket closes and is not working further. How to keep the socket alive?

Thank you for your help

Comment: If you telnet (presumably since using port 23) to the device and issue the command manually using the telnet command does it return what you are expected ?

Comment: When I do the telnet like this:
Telnet 192.168.1.23 23 -> Returns blank console for few moments and then goes back to cmd
When I do it like this:
Telnet 192.168.1.23 23 AT+SENSOR_IDS\r\n -> It results in cmd giving me help for the Telnet command.
I have never used telnet commands, is the output alright?

Comment: Can you give any details on what the remote host is ? what type of device ? link to a API or Protocol spec ?

Comment: Unfortunately, this device is state-of-the-art device without any documentation available. The only thing I have is the IP, port, that it communicates over TCP/IP and the format of the AT commands

Comment: Are you sure your format of the AT commands is correct ? the error you have suggests the device is closing the connection for some reason, usually this is upon receipt of an invalid command

Answer (score 0):

You must close the sockets that you opened otherwise they will be open until a timeout reached.

Try this:

```py
import socket
import time
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='conn.txt', filemode='w')

logging.warning('Starting...')
address = ('192.168.1.23', 23)
soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    ok = soc.connect_ex(address)

    if ok == 0:
        logging.warning('Connected to device ' + str(ok))
    else:
        logging.warning('Connection failed ' + str(ok))
except Exception as e:
    soc.close()
    print("Connection is not successful, error returned :", e)

try:
    ### send at command
    command = 'AT+SENSOR_IDS'
    cmd_to_send = command + '\r\n'
    cmd_to_send = cmd_to_send.encode('ascii')
    logging.warning('Sending at command')

    soc.sendall(cmd_to_send)
    logging.warning('at command sent, waiting for echo')

    # read echo
    echo = soc.recv()
    logging.warning('received echo: ' + echo)
except:
    try:
        soc.close()
        print('Process Finished Succefully')
    except:
        print('Process Finished Socket Exception Occured')
```

Comment: Like this, the error doesn't come out, but then the program does following:
When it tries, to send the AT command, it fails, and so goes to the except statement, there it succesfully closes the socket and prints 'Process finished succesfully'. Maybe I understand the whole concept wrong -  I understand it in the way, that I open the socket for communication, connect it to the host and then send the command and after that close the socket. But like this (in the code you provided), the at command is never sent.

Comment: This answer doesnt address the issue that the connection gets closed, it just enabled the correct handling of the error.